# What sort of server to use for a scalable PHP project?

Tags: php, facebook, yii, appfog, pagoda-box

I just started a project in a company, they had it hosted on Google App Engine and the app was developed in Java. The thing is that this code was totally unreadable. So I've came to the conclusion that the best solution would be start it all over.

Because it is a Facebook App, one approach would be to stop using Java and start using their available PHP SDK. But, Google App Engine still doesn't work well with PHP, we can't install Frameworks like Yii without workarounds, etc.

So I think the best solution would be change the place that we are hosting the application. It needs to be a host for scalable PHP applications.

I've researched a little bit and found people talking about Pagoda and appfog.

Do you have any suggestions? What is the best solution considering: price, efficiency and also it needs to be easy to use. I don't have a lot of experiences managing servers, I usually have someone on the company that takes care of all of that for me.

Comment: This question might be better suited for another StackExchange site, but it is off topic here. Questions here should be about specific coding problems that involve code. This doesn't have anything to do with the actual writing of code so it is off topic.

Comment: Swapping language and platform sounds rather drastic. Would it be cheaper and less hassle to get a Java freelancer in, either to walk you through the existing code, and/or to tidy it up a bit?

Comment: We've decided to do that because the existing project it's in very bad conditions. I develop for Java too, but we are in a situation that is better to start everything from zero than to keep working on the existing project. 

The reason why we've decided to change to PHP its because Facebook doesnt give support for Java, if you want to develop a Java app for Facebook you need to use 3rd party Apis. But with PHP we can use Facebook PHP SDK which is much more realiable than 3rd party ones.

Answer (score 2):

My best advice would be to choose a standard Cloud provider like DigitalOcean, VPS.net or AWS. You get full access to the server to configure and install anything you like, and they often come with pre-built server images with PHP/MySQL/Apache already configured and ready to use.

Comment: Thanks! I think we'll go with AWS :)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has PHP support to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php and it's ideal for FB apps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook